# Bad request 400 while trying to do partial update with UpdateAPIView

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, model, serialization

I am using DRF UpdateAPIView to take in PATCH method and partially update my model. It should by default handel correctly partial update but i somehow get Bad request error. What could be issue here?

View:

```
class ProfileViewUpdate(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    lookup_field = 'token'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'pk'

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['partial'] = True
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Serializer:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('token', 'bio', 'name', 'email', 'sport', 'location', 'image')
```

Comment: Checkout if this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56579415/patch-method-in-django-rest-returns-400-bad-request) helps.

Comment: Not much because i am using DRF generic view

Comment: ok, two things: 1. which django version are you using. You can find this out by running following command: `pip freeze | grep djangorestframework==` 2. can you can update your question with StackTrace of this 400 Error that's logged in you console from where you are running sever?

Comment: It is same error in terminal, bad request

Comment: you should have a detailed stacktrace in your terminal with the line where the error occurs. UpdateAPIView have UpdateModelMixin inside, so you can delete your def partial_update. Can you show your model Profile ? and your url called, you need to pass an 'pk' argument

Comment: I figured out it should be something done with my image not being in right format. Beacause i can update my fields like name and email. But error comes in when i try to patch my image file

Comment: Maybe you need to convert it into some format before uploading but i dont know that.